# Converting HTML to text then back to HTML to add to page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

We are using an XML feed to show some data, we use jquery and ajax to make the call. Once we have the data I am trying to parse it correctly.

```
var des = $(this).find("Description").text();
var trimmed= des.substring(0, 300);

if (trimmed.length <= 300) {
    trimmed += "...";
}
var $des = $('<div class="linkitem"></div>').html(trimmed);

if (count == 1) {
    var wrapper = "<div class='item active'>";
} else {
    var wrapper = "<div class='item'>";
}

var wrapperEnd = "</div>";
$(".carousel-inner").append($(wrapper).append($link, $location, $category, 
    $emptype, $des, $(wrapperEnd)));
```

The issue I am having is with the Description field. The data originally starts as html once I get the data I get it as .text() which would return this for example:

```
 &lt;p&gt;&lt;em&gt;This&lt;/em&gt; is a &lt;strong&gt;test&lt;/strong&gt; job &lt;span style=&quot;text-decoration: underline;&quot;&gt;description&lt;/span&gt;.&lt;/p&gt;
```

We then trim this to be only 300 chars, which I understand is a bit risky as we might half cut off a html tag, but that is what we are doing at the moment.

I then need to add this trimmed description into a div on the html page. The issue is that it currently adds like this:

```
<div class="linkitem">&lt;p&gt;&lt;strong&gt;This&lt;/strong&gt; is &lt;em&gt;the&lt;/em&gt; job &lt;span style="text-decoration: underline;"&gt;description&lt;/span&gt;.&amp;nbsp;&lt;/p&gt;...</div>
```

So it doesn't appear to convert it back to html for the page to render correctly. Can someone tell me where I might be going wrong?

---- EDIT ----
Change attempt:

```
var desString = $.parseHTML(trimmed);
var $des = $('<div class="linkitem"></div>').html(desString);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just use jQuery's built in $.parseHTML Function.

```js
var str = `&lt;p&gt;&lt;strong&gt;This&lt;/strong&gt; is &lt;em&gt;the&lt;/em&gt; job &lt;span style="text-decoration: underline;"&gt;description&lt;/span&gt;.&amp;nbsp;&lt;/p&gt;`

    var html = $("<div />").html(str).text();

    $("#text").append(html);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="text"></div>
```

You also wanted to try removing tags, you can do a simple replace function:

```js
var str = $("#html").html();

//Thanks: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/javascript/strip-html-tags-in-javascript/
$(function() {
      $("#result").append(str.replace(/(<([^>]+)>)/ig, ""));
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="html" style="display:none">
  <h1>HTML Ipsum Presents</h1>

  <p><strong>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique</strong> senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. <em>Aenean ultricies mi vitae est.</em> Mauris
    placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed, <code>commodo vitae</code>, ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum orci, sagittis
    tempus lacus enim ac dui. <a href="#">Donec non enim</a> in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis.</p>

  <h2>Header Level 2</h2>

  <ol>
    <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.</li>
    <li>Aliquam tincidunt mauris eu risus.</li>
  </ol>

  <blockquote>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus magna. Cras in mi at felis aliquet congue. Ut a est eget ligula molestie gravida. Curabitur massa. Donec eleifend, libero at sagittis mollis, tellus est malesuada tellus, at luctus turpis
      elit sit amet quam. Vivamus pretium ornare est.</p>
  </blockquote>

  <h3>Header Level 3</h3>

  <ul>
    <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.</li>
    <li>Aliquam tincidunt mauris eu risus.</li>
  </ul>

  <pre><code>
#header h1 a { 
 display: block; 
 width: 300px; 
 height: 80px; 
}
</code></pre>
</div>
<div id="result"></div>
```

Comment: I tried to do that but get the same result. See my edit to see where I am made that relevant change. It is still appended to the overall generated html in the same way

Comment: Edited, try to run the snippet again.

Comment: Thanks, is there anyway I could take a different approach and remove all the HTML tags from the original text, just leaving plain text instead?

Comment: I've edited the previous answer for leaving plaintext

Comment: Thanks, but sorry for being stupid... How would I get that into what I currently have?

Comment: `$(this).find("Description").text().replace(/(<([^>]+)>)/ig, "").substring(0, 300);`

Comment: Thanks, amongst this I went with the original approach as found that were the full html could possibly be received the replace would then not work and leave a half tag like <span="text-... therefore it made more sense to keep them and just remove styles. Thanks